# specific driver and motor combination

Tags: motor, driver, stepper-motor, 3d

I am planning to make a 3D printer for a school project and would be grateful for your help. I want to **combine the following driver** [L298N Dual H Bridge DC Motor Driver IC; Driven part of the terminal supply area Vs: +5 V ~ +35 V; such as the need to take power within the board, the supply area Vs: +7 V ~ +35 V; Driven part of the peak current Io: 2A. The logical part of the terminal supply area Vss: +5 V ~ +7 V (can take power within the board +5 V) The logical part of the operating current range: 0 ~ 36mA] 
**with** **a stepper motor** (1.8⁰ Cool Stepper Motors High Torque Hybrid, BH42 SH 47 - 1504 AF, NEMA 17(42 mm) Frame size, Bipolar (4 leads), Holding Torque 5.5 kgcm (0.55 Nm), Current per phase 1.5 Amp) 
I would like to use three of these drives each connected to one stepper motor. **Can I use this combination?** 
Also, I hope to use an old computer's PSU to power these. **Would a 12-16V PSU work to power all three drivers connected in parallel? How high can I go in terms of DC voltage? Each motor is 1.5 A and so I guess 4.5 A has to be the upper limit of the power supply?** Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please don't be afraid to break your text into logical paragraphs. We love schematics. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

1) For a bipolar stepper motor, both windings are driven at the same time, so each motor will require 3 amps, for a total of 9 amps.

2) One L298 per motor will work, BUT

3) You MUST provide PWM control with a current control loop. The winding resistance is 2.8 ohms, so a DC voltage of more than 4.2 volts will overdrive the motor. With a 12-volt PSU, this means no more than 35% duty cycle, and kHz pulse rates. You may find making this controller a challenge. If so, drive the motor with about 4.2 volts, rather than 12-16. If  you do this, you can just provide phase control and not worry about the current limits.

Comment: One caveat to reducing the voltage and just providing phase control: A reduced voltage results in a reduced di/dt ... You can't step as fast. Before chopper drives came into fashion, stepper drives often used power resistors in series with the coils and drove with higher voltages.